# How to display entire comments in separate page

Tags: nodes, comments, 7

I know we can display reply form in separate page. But now I having the requirement of displaying entire comments and reply form in separate page. Is there have any way to display those in separate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Talk](http://drupal.org/project/talk) module shows the comments for a node in a tab added to the node page.

> The talk module removes comments from the node page and puts them on a separate tab. This style of commenting is very popular on Wiki sites (usually called the "discussion" page) and on news websites where the goal is to separate user generated content from editorial content.
>
> When installed this module will add a tab to the set of tabs at the top of a node view page like "View | Edit | Talk" and provides a link at the bottom of the node to go to the talk page and view comments.